# How do I limit Remote Desktop Connection access using GPO's in Active Directore

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, remote-desktop, windows-server-2019

I am pretty new to designing Active Directory domains and using GPO to make settings ont he local machine.  However, I have been set a task and am struggling.

I have a Server 2019 virtual instance Domain Controller and two virtual Windows 10 instances running on ESXi 7.0, lets call them machines A and B, joined to the domain.

I have three users X, Y and Z.

User X needs to be allowed to access either machine A or machine B.

User Y should only be allowed to access machine A, User Z should only be allowed to access machine B

I have created OU's nested so that there is a top OU, and inside that two more OU's A and B.  Inside OU A I have put machine A and a security group AUsers.  Inside OU B I have put machine B and security group BUsers.  I have added User X to both security groups, User Y to AUsers and User Z BUsers.  I have added these security groups to the local machines 'Remote Desktop Users' group.

However I am getting errors stating that users do not have remote desktop permission when I try to connect using a Remote Desktop Connection form a third non-domain joined machine.

Do I need to add these security groups to the Domain Remote Desktop Users group?  Or should I add the specific users?

I have seen instructions regarding the need to create a GPO that adds the AUsers group to the Restricted Groups but I'm really not sure I understand what Restricted Groups are - if anyone can point to some resources, I've been googling it with a lot of confusing info found... Any pointers to great resources or training would be very greatfully received also!

Comment: If the account cannot logon if the account is a direct member of the target system's Remote Desktop Users group, it probably is not the groups. If it can, it could be an incorrect group scope.

Comment: So you are setting up a RDS farm with license servers and everything, right? Because Remote Desktop Sessions like "access either machine A or machine B" are not included in Windows Server without RD licensing. If done so, think about using RD Collection on your broker.